# Is it possible to add the 'sizes' property to a <link> element created by javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on building a plugin for an existing content framework, and need to add  elements to the header for mobile favicon support. The only access I am given to do so with the plugin architecture is utilizing javascript. I have successfully written the plugin which generates the  elements, but the 'sizes' property is not being included in the generated code, likely as it is an HTML5 property. Is there a cross-browser way to do this?

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'apple-touch-icon';
link.sizes = '57x57';
link.href = '/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png';
document.head.appendChild(link);
```

Generated code (as viewed in Chrome v41's Inspect Element tool):

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
```

Comment: @RickHitchcock another case where w3schools is a terrible reference

Comment: Found a better reference.  The `sizes` attribute is not supported by any major browser:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the setAttribute method:

```
link.setAttribute("sizes","57x57")
```

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN docs `sizes` is only applicable when `rel="icon"` is used

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

Also note that IOS doesn't recognize attribute